# How to do a blank space in Java error message?

Tags: java

I am trying to show user an error message. What should I use for breaking line and creating blank space in Java, which `<br>` and `&nbsp` are normally being used in HTML?

So the output would be like:

```
# Session expired
  Sesi tamat
```

instead of

```
# Session expired Sesi tamat
```

My attempt:

```
errors.add("Session expired" + "   " + "Sesi tamat");
```

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks.

---EDIT---

I tried with html tag, which `<br/>` is working but `<pre> </pre>` and `<&nbsp>` are not.

PS: I tag Java only since I do not know what else should I tag.

Comment: So your output is displayed by something that renders html?

Comment: Yes, I am using the html way to do the break line. If not, anyway to do with Java for the break line?

Comment: It's not `$nbsp` in HTML. It's `&nbsp;`. If whatever you're using to display text understands `<br/>`, it probably also understands `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @Brian your output is shown in some component that renders html, maybe even a browser. Since you don't clarify this, it's hard to say which options you have.

Comment: @slim it works now with &nbsp before the second line of message. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the following

```
errors.add("Session expired" + "<br/><pre> </pre>" + "Sesi tamat");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does not work in the way like the desired output. Maybe the html tag is not ideal with my issue.

Comment: @BrianCheong where's the error message output? to the console or html page?

Comment: @cjslv to the html page

Comment: @BrianCheong have you tried adding `&nbsp;` right before "Sesi tamat"?

Comment: nbsp is short for NonBreakingSPace. It is meant that you create blanks with it.